# TTS throw NPE while using Android 2.2,but it works fine 4.0 version

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My apps is working fine in 4.0 version,but if i use in 2.2 it showing my app force close.
While checking in logcat it shows error in tts function,TTS throws NPE.I initialized TTS initialization also.Lower version only make problem.

This is myactivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item2);

        mDbHelper = new GinfyDbAdapter(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnadd1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        lv = getListView();
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                if(count>0)
                {
                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)

                {Log.i("checked content Inside on click of share ",""+aa.get(i));
                    if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         result.append("Title:");
                         result.append(bb.get(i));

                         result.append("\n");
                         result.append("Content:");
                         result.append(aa.get(i));
                         result.append("\n");

                    }

                }
                }
               // }
                Log.i("result is",""+result);
                if(result!=null)
                {
                 showAlertView(result.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("result is","null");
                }

            }

        });

        btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                createProject();


            }

        });

        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());


    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData() {
        mDbHelper.open();      
        Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();

      count = projectsCursor.getCount();

        Log.i(".......fill data method logging now ......",""+count);
        if (projectsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {

                  int col1 = projectsCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
                  String title = projectsCursor.getString(col1 );         
                  bb.add(title);              

                  int col2 = projectsCursor.getColumnIndex("content");
                  String content = projectsCursor.getString(col2 );         
                  aa.add(content);
                  Log.i("...........................All COntent",content);
              } while (projectsCursor.moveToNext());

        }
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);


        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE,GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT,GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text22,R.id.text11,R.id.date};
        dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter (YourPrayerActivity .this, R.layout.row2, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(dataAdapter);



        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return mDbHelper.fetchProjectByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });



        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text11);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                //btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }



    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(YourPrayerActivity.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }*/


    private void createProject() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddyourprayerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);  
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }


    private void speakOut() {

        // String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        // String text = "Android speech";

        tts.speak(typed, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ListView lv;




        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
                 {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(c.getCount());



            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


         @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor){
                int row_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");  //Your row id (might need to replace)
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text22);
                final TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text11);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                int col1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
                final String title = cursor.getString(col1 );
                int col2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("content");
                final String content = cursor.getString(col2 );
                int col3 = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
                final String date = cursor.getString(col3);
                cb.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(cursor.getPosition(), false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
              //  TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                //cursor.getColumnName(1)
                tv.setText( title);
                tv1.setText( content);
                tv2.setText(date);
                //tv2.setText( ""+cursor.getColumnIndex(GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT));
             //   String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT}
                ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sms1);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
                    sb2.append("Title:");
                        sb2.append(Html.fromHtml(title));
                        sb2.append(",Content:");
                        sb2.append(Html.fromHtml(content));
                        sb2.append("\n");
                        String strContactList1 = (sb2.toString().trim());
                        sendsmsdata(strContactList1);
                    }
                });

                ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.mail1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        StringBuffer sb3 = new StringBuffer();
                    sb3.append("Title:");
                        sb3.append(Html.fromHtml(title));
                        sb3.append(",Content:");
                        sb3.append(Html.fromHtml(content));
                        sb3.append("\n");
                        String strContactList2 = (sb3.toString().trim());
                        sendmaildata(strContactList2);
                    }
                });

                ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer1);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        //ADD STUFF HERE you know which row is clicked. and which button
                        typed = content;
                        speakOut();
                    }
                });



            }
```

Here i paste my logcat error while using android 2.2

```
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:143)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(TextToSpeech.java:720)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.example.tesing.YourPrayerActivity.speakOut(YourPrayerActivity.java:258)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.example.tesing.YourPrayerActivity.onInit(YourPrayerActivity.java:212)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:451)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1264)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-24 12:51:45.074: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It shows error in those lines
                                 speakOut();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to initialize your string variable.

I think in your case `typed` is the variable.

Wherever you're initializing it, initialize in this way:

```
public String typed = "" ;
```

It'll work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to **print the Log or to show toast message with NULL** values.Hence you are getting java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message